# Show the message in the same page with out going to the next page?

Tags: visualforce, rendered, outputtext, outputpanel

I am getting the list from the controller :

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(quo))}">
                 <apex:outputText rendered="{!quo.size>999 }" value="Refine search Records should be less than 1000" />
</apex:outputPanel>
```

i want to show this "Refine search Records should be less than 1000" without going into the next page with the below error .

I am getting the message like this :

> Visualforce Error
>
> Collection size 1 125 exceeds maximum size of 1 000.

How can i do that stay on the same page and show the message .

Comment: How about instead of using panel just add message in controller?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the action method you are using to move to the next page:

```
public PageReference next() {
    if (quo.size() <= 1000) {
        return Page.TheNextPage;
    } else {
        Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info,'Refine search Records should be less than 1000'));
        return null; // Stay on same page
    }
}
```

If you are still hitting the error then you could use [limit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_limit.htm) to restrict the search results to 1000 and then display a message to let the user know that this has happened.

```
[select Id from Quote limit:1000];
```

Answer (score 0):

Governor limits cannot be handled on Apex code and Visualforce page like other exceptions.

In you scenario you can check collection size in Apex controller and show error on visualforce page

In Code

```
List<Account> accToAddInSelectOption = [SELECT id FROM Account];
if(accToAddInSelectOption.size()>=1000)
{
  Apexpages.addmessage(new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info,'Total Number of Records Exceed:' + accToAddInSelectOption.size());
}
```

In page add following Apex tag:

```
<apex:form >
        <apex:messages/>
</apex:form>
```